# Logitech unifying receiver can't wakeup laptop, but non-logitech wifi mouse can

Tags: usb, keyboard, suspend, logitech

I have a Logitech Unifying Receiver with a model K780 keyboard and M310 mouse paired to it. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. My laptop is HP ProBook 470 G1. I have executed `echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb$1/power/wakeup` for all my usb ports.

Neither the logitech keyboard nor the mouse wake the laptop up, even though a different, non-Logitech wifi mouse does wake up the laptop when connected to the same port. Since a non-Logitech mouse can wake the laptop up, I assume the issue is not with the USB port, but rather with the unifying receiver or Logitech products in general.

I found a reference to the same problem (logitech can't wakeup but non-logitech can) [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/835470/10263):

> But i can wake with wireless devices that are non-Logitech, non-unifying receiver like Nulaxy ML11 2.4GHz Wireless Mouse

Is this a known issue with Logitech products?

Comment: I would check your actual system & it's updates, a fully upgraded Ubuntu *bionic* system will report itself as 18.04.5, if yours says 18.04.3 then you've not applied upgrades for over 18 months (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/ shows the date of 18.04.5 ISO release; installed systems upgraded before that date and a fully upgraded system reports itself as 18.04.5)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to enable `3-4` as opposed to e.g. `usb3`:

```
echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-4/power/wakeup
```

Unfortunately this allows the mouse movements to wake the laptop as well since it's paired to the same unifying receiver.

I hope I'll find a way to distinguish between paired devices on the same receiver.